# sql server need to pad column left with zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to pad my column left with zeros up to 7. Some are already 7 digits already but anything that isn't 7 digits needs a leading 0. What is the best way to code this?

Comment: I realize that the other link is for 3 digits instead of 7, but I think that you can probably extrapolate out there. Took all of 3 seconds to find that.

Answer (score 5):

You can just do:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),YourNumber),7)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work? SELECT FORMAT(YourNumber, '0000000')
 FROM table

Comment: @KevinM Hadn't noticed that you were using SQL Server 2014, but well, that should work, what do you mean it doesn't?